# Symbolizing raster layer with Python QGIS

Tags: pyqgis, raster-calculator, color-ramp

I have a simple Python code that makes some calculations on rasters and give me some output rasters; I have also a style saved to color rasters based on pixel values.
Is there an option to load the output (single-band) rasters with the color style I want in stead to have them in black and white?

```
from qgis.analysis import QgsRasterCalculator, QgsRasterCalculatorEntry
b=[12.158, 13.094, 15.961, 19.553, 24.669, 29.16, 31.805, 31.615, 27.284, 22.286, 17.026, 13.31]
s=['Tmaxjan', 'Tmaxfeb','Tmaxmar','Tmaxapr','Tmaxmay','Tmaxjun','Tmaxjul','Tmaxaug','Tmaxsep','Tmaxoct','Tmaxnov','Tmaxdec']


path = '/Users/macbook/Desktop/TESI/PROGETTO/raster_T_max/'

list=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]
for i in list:

  rasterfile = QgsRasterLayer('/Users/macbook/Desktop/TESI/PROGETTO/DEM CAPITANATA.tif')

  entries = []
  ras1 = QgsRasterCalculatorEntry()
  ras1.ref = 'ras@1'
  ras1.raster = rasterfile
  ras1.bandNumber = 1
  entries.append( ras1 )

  new_path = path + s[i]+ '.tif'

  temperature = str(b[i]) + "+" + '(-0.007)' + '* ras@1 '

  Temp = QgsRasterCalculator(temperature, new_path, 'GTiff', rasterfile.extent(), rasterfile.width(), rasterfile.height(), entries )

  Temp.processCalculation()
  iface.addRasterLayer(new_path)
```

Comment: You can apply either interpolated, discrete, or exact color ramp depending on your preferences using QgsColorRampShader as shown in this tutorial:https://opensourceoptions.com/blog/loading-and-symbolizing-raster-layers/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add a raster layer and then apply a custom style to it:

```
rasterlayer = iface.addRasterLayer(rasterlayer_path)
rasterlayer.loadNamedStyle(style_path)
iface.layerTreeView().refreshLayerSymbology(rasterlayer.id())
rasterlayer.triggerRepaint()
```

Where: `rasterlayer_path` contains the path string of the raster layer and `style_path` contains the path string of the .qml QGIS Layer Style file.

For more info, see:

- https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/loadlayer.html#raster-layers
- https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/raster.html
- https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.16/core/QgsMapLayer.html#qgis.core.QgsMapLayer.triggerRepaint

Answer (score 1):

If you already have a saved .qml style file which you would like to apply to your loaded raster, you can do it like this. Just change the `style_path` variable to point to the location of your saved style file:

```py
# ...the previous part of your code
Temp.processCalculation()

# add lines below
rasterlayer = iface.addRasterLayer(new_path)

# change path below to point to your saved style file
style_path = '/Users/macbook/path/to/named_style.qml'

rasterlayer.loadNamedStyle(style_path)

iface.layerTreeView().refreshLayerSymbology(rasterlayer.id())

# (Optional) if you want to expand the layer item in the legend, add the lines below
legenditem = iface.layerTreeView().model().rootGroup().findLayer(rasterlayer)
legenditem.setExpanded(True)
```

Comment: I tried but anyway, it printed the output rasters in black and white...

Comment: @Rapu93, are you sure that you specified the correct path to your .qml file?

Comment: Yes the path is correct